# How to divide minute by 3 in PHP ?

Tags: php, division, operation, divide, integer-division

How to divide *time* by 3?
I know  `$minute%3==0` could work if minute is 0,3,9,12,15...

But how to judge if minute is 1,4,10,13,16, if minute is 2,5,11,14,17?

Thanks.

```
$minute = date('i');
if($minute%3==0){
  //if minute is 0,3,9,12,15...do something
}else if($minute%3+1==0){
  //if minute is 1,4,10,13,16...do something
}else if($minute%3+2==0){
  //if minute is 2,5,11,14,17...do something
}
```

Comment: ...answer as feddus has done it below ... but I would recommend using a switch statement as a cleaner way to write the code. Using lots of else if makes it much harder to follow for anyone else looking at the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it by checking the remainder of dividing by 3:

```
$minute = date('i');
if($minute%3==0){
  //if minute is 0,3,9,12,15...do something
}else if($minute%3==1){
  //if minute is 1,4,10,13,16...do something
}else if($minute%3==2){
  //if minute is 2,5,11,14,17...do something
}
```